# Android drawing - Background caching

Tags: android

Quick question - I'm having control that's extending LinearLayout and I'm overriding it's onPaint method like this

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);

    _background.draw(canvas);
    _object1.draw(canvas);
    _object2.draw(canvas);
    _object3.draw(canvas);

    // etc...

}
```

Every 40ms I invoke postInvalidate() in background and onPaint gets called on UI thread. The problem is _background.draw is taking over 80% of my drawing time.

So - is it possible to somehow cache background and not redraw it every time?

Comment: Why are you invalidating every 40ms?  Are the objects moving across the background or are the objects themselves changing but staying in the same relative position?

Comment: Objects are both moving and changing (moving animation)... there are moments when they are standing, but that's special case (<10% of time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a region to `postInvalidate()` to control the area that gets redrawn.

Comment: Uf... I'm really blind when I missed that overload. So am I getting this right:

-I can post multiple regions in for(Rect r : regions) and it will only draw that parts no matter if I refresh everything in onDraw (tried it right now and it seems it works that way)?
-There is no such thing as to put one LinearLayout over other; put background image on bottom one, invalidate top that has transparent background and see that things magically work out (Android invalidates right regions for me)?

Comment: Also, one more thing, if you know. Suppose I have 320x480 screen. I call canvas.drawBitmap with image that's 600x800. Will that bigger image draw in same time as if I crop it's top-left 320x480 part (in Photoshop) before compiling?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Actually, I'm new to this as well, but trying to come up to speed as fast as I can.  I'm mostly answering based on what I've been reading.  You can put Drawables on multiple layers, though and manage them with LayerDrawable.  If it were me, I think I would start there.